# Gather Layer Borders data through Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I am writing an own tool for profiling my web performance issues. I spotted an necessity to observer amount of separate composite layers on my website. I am looking through web APIs on MDN, but I can't find any suitable API. Do you know if there is any possibility to gather that data on website, through javascript? 
To be specific i need the data displayed inside the 'Layers borders' option located inside 'Rendering' tab in Chome Developer Tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an LayersTree API in DevTool protocol https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/LayerTree.

Layers list can be easily achieved by `LayerTree.layerTreeDidChange` callback parameter.